# What does variable = self mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
 class trial(object):
      def __init__(self):
        sup = ''
        sup = self
        print sup

 trial_1 = trial()
```

The assignment operations `self.var = var` make good sense, but assigning a variable on the left side `self` - (a) what does this mean? And moreover, (b) why would any program do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sup` is merely another reference to `self` now; both names refer to the *same object*.

As to why it would do that, there could be any number of reasons, but we'd need more context.

If you were going to rebind the `sup` name later on but need `self` as a starting point, the assignment might make sense. A graph traversal springs to mind, where the algorithm starts at `self` and then, in a loop, iteratively assigns child nodes to the same variable name:

```
sup = self
while sup.has_children():
    sup = sup.get_first_child()
```

Except I'd pick a better name than `sup`.

Answer (score 3):

Like any other assignment, it simply creates another name pointing at the `self` object.

As to why, that's a good question: it doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: @WLin Why to assign it in some other variable to do that? You can straight away use `self`.

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking of something unrelated. I have deleted my previous comment.